# Showing two images in one ViewController picked with UIImagePickerController from different buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I created a ViewController where I have two images avatar and coverPhoto and two buttons. Clicking on the first button (changeAvatar) I call an action sheet where I can choose between "taking photo from library" or "take a new image". The second button does the same but for cover photo.

ProfileViewController.h

```
@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatar;

- (IBAction)changeAvatar:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changeUserCover:(id)sender;
```

In implementation file:

```
@synthesize cover;
@synthesize avatar;

- (IBAction)changeAvatar:(id)sender{

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set your avatar" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Choose existing photo", @"Take new photo", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
NSLog(@"The %@ library button was tapped.", [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

 }

else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

    NSLog(@"The %@ camera button was tapped.", [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

}
```

Image picker controller for avatar:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.avatar.image = chosenImage;
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

I did the same for the second button but when I click the button picked image (coverPhoto) goes to the avatar image.

I was trying with “tags” to identify which button invoke the action. But it doesn’t work. Do you have any ideas ho to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an enumerated type `CurrentImageCategory` as,

```
typedef enum {
CurrentImageCategoryAvatar = 0,
CurrentImageCategoryCover
}CurrentImageCategory;
```

Use `userDefaults` to store current image category or you can manage your own property in your class.

```
- (IBAction)changeAvatar:(id)sender{
  // Set current category to userDefaults
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:CurrentImageCategoryAvatar forKey:@"currentImageCategory"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

  // Your code
}
```

Use the same for cover image,

```
- (IBAction)changeUserCover:(id)sender{
  // Set current category to userDefaults
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:CurrentImageCategoryCover forKey:@"currentImageCategory"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

  // Your code
}
```

Then in `imagePickerController` check `currentImageCategory`

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentImageCategory"] == CurrentImageCategoryAvatar)
    {
        // Set image to avatar
    }
    else if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentImageCategory"] == CurrentImageCategoryCover)
    {
       // Set image to cover
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you probably know how to transfer these images to another view controller?